# when executing procedure getting "not a valid month error" in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here im comparing hiredate and sysdate where i want hire date less than sysdate. but im getting error. how to solve this error.

```
Create or replace procedure example
   ( hire_date IN  date)
  IS 
  
Begin
    IF (TO_DATE (hire_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') < TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))  THEN
INSERT INTO EMP (EMP_ID,
                     EMP_NAME,
                     EMAIL,
                     PHONE_NUMBER,
                     HIRE_DATE,
                     JOB_ID,
                     SAL)
                     values(empinc.nextval, 'ravi','ravi@gmail.com','6578940983456',TO_DATE ('7/20/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'JUN_TECH',60000);
                     
                     INSERT INTO EMP (EMP_ID,
                     EMP_NAME,
                     EMAIL,
                     PHONE_NUMBER,
                     HIRE_DATE,
                     JOB_ID,
                     SAL)
                     values(empinc.nextval, 'ravi','ravi@gmail.com','6578940983456',TO_DATE ('5/27/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'JUN_TECH',60000);
                     
                     INSERT INTO EMP (EMP_ID,
                     EMP_NAME,
                     EMAIL,
                     PHONE_NUMBER,
                     HIRE_DATE,
                     JOB_ID,
                     SAL)
                     values(empinc.nextval, 'ravi','ravi@gmail.com','6578940983456',TO_DATE ('3/22/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'JUN_TECH',60000);
                     else
                     dbms_output.put_line('failed');
end if;
END;
/
```

Here im comparing hiredate and sysdate where i want hire date less than sysdate. but im getting error. how to solve this error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to reproduce the exact error but this line is definitely wrong:

```
IF (TO_DATE (hire_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') < TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))  THEN
```

The argument `hire_date` is of data type `DATE` and so is `sysdate`. The function `TO_DATE` converts a **string** in a given format to a date. For comparing dates, TO_DATE is not needed.

Change it to

```
IF hire_date < SYSDATE THEN
```

You don't show *how* you're getting the error. What command are you executing that throws this error ?

Comment: IF hire_date < SYSDATE THEN this one already tried not working

Comment: pls update your question with an answer to my last question. You're just showing code. You're not showing what you are executing that throws this error. My answer is just a guess because the most important info is missing